# How can i run socket server in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, server

How can i run socket server for each www client?

I have simple socket_server:

```
<?php
// set ip and port
include('socket.php');
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "-1";
    exit;
} 

// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3);

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

echo "Server: Ready.";

while(1) {
    // read client input
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
    // clean up input string
    $input = trim($input);
    echo "Client Message : ".$input."<br />";
    // reverse client input and send back
    //$output = strrev($input) ."<br />";

    $output = "output message";
    socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
}

// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Now when i try run server in this way:

```
<?php

//include the server.php script to start the server
include_once('server.php');

include('socket.php');

$message = "Hello Server";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I get the message:

> *Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.*

I do not have any other communications on this port. I checked the netstat.

Comment: Should you be running the server in a separate script (process) that sits waiting for connections from the client?

Comment: When i run server in a separate process (from command line) then server works fine. But i must run server In the same way as I showed in first post (without command line).